# Ember.js and Rails model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

Just would like to know how to do a model association when using Ember.js and rails.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your models manually with your own defined emberjs objects or you can look into the Ember Data persistance library. https://github.com/emberjs/data